# How to export python list into excel file using xlwt?

Tags: python, list, xlwt

Here I am trying to export python list to the excel file but it is not working correctly.

The list will be dynamic.

```
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="excle_file.xls"'

wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
ws = wb.add_sheet('datas', cell_overwrite_ok=True)

row_num = 0

font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
font_style.font.bold = True

columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5']

for col_num in range(len(columns)):
    ws.write(row_num, col_num, columns[col_num], font_style)

font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
rows = [20, Decimal('50000.00'), Decimal('10.00'), Decimal('40000.00'), Decimal('90000.00'), 21, Decimal('31000.00'), Decimal('2000.00'), Decimal('41000.00'), Decimal('74000.00')]

for i,e in enumerate(rows):
   ws.write(i,1, e)

wb.save(response)
return response
```

I want response like this.

```
col1  col2   col3  col4  col5
20    50000   10   40000  90000
21    31000   2000 41000  74000
```

Current response

```
col1  col2   col3  col4  col5
      20    
      50000  
      10   
      40000  
      90000
      21    
      31000  
      ....
```

Also I want to increase the size of the column based on the text? How it will be done ?

Answer (score 1):

Per the docs https://xlwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlwt.Worksheet.Worksheet ws.write takes (row,column,value). Compare what you get if you change:

```
ws.write(i,1, e)
```

to:

```
print(i,1, e)
```

and then how it changes if you put:

```
print(int(i/5),int(i)%5, e)
```

Comment: thanks +1 it solved one probelm but now the columns name `col1`, `col2`..  are missing

Comment: I've never used xlwt so guessing here, but change to int(i/5)+1 ? Before it started on row 0 which is where you've put the column names.